# ProgressBar doesn't fill as its width

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

In `C# Winform`s, I have a `BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1` and `ProgressBar progressBar1`. 
   Properties of `ProgressBar` are : `Min =0, Max =100, Step=1, Value = 0 Size-W-508, H=23`. 
   In my `DoWork()`, I call `ReportProgress(70, "Transferring")` in this way.

In `ProgressChanged()` :

```
    string status = (string)e.UserState;
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    progressBar1.Refresh();
```

The `ProgressBar` is changing and its value is also changing. I also track the `progressBar1.Value` and its showing the proper results.

But when 70 is passed and is set as `ProgressPercent`, then why 70% of the `width` of `progressBar1` is not covered. Even when passing 100, full width of progressbasr is not covered. I tried to set the Max of `ProgressBar` as 508 (i.e. Width of the ProgressBar), but that also didn't worked.

I surfed many sites, but didn't find this sort of problem in any. 
Can you please point out what and where am I going wrong ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try change your `Step` to 1.

Comment: Have tried with that also. Right now it's 1 only. But same results.

Answer (score 0):

After trying more and more, just tried one more thing which was sure that it wont make any difference; But it worked.

Added the following code before calling `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` :

```
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            progressBar1.Step = 1;
            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;

            transferFileType = 'R';
            connecting = true;
            statusBarLbl.Text = "Processing.....Transferring Report Files to PC ";
            progressStatusLbl.Text = "Retrieving Device Id and Info";
            // Start the asynchronous operation
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

and it worked as I wanted it. Rest all code was the same. Just added the above 4 properties of the progress bar.

Surprising, the same properties are already set of the `ProgressBar` and it's even being used for the first time, yet before accessing it needed to set its properties to work !!!!

Hope it might help someone.

Thanks